# SQL case in where condition not working

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

I am trying to write a dynamic SQL statement depending upon not null condition. Basically I have a stored procedure and that has 2 input parameters i.e. ip1 and ip2. ip1 will have value all the time but ip2 may or may not have values as i/p parameter. So I am trying to write a query using case like below. I am basically trying to add the ip2 condition in the where clause only if ip2 id not null as i/p parameter. If ip2 is null, then just add ip1 condition. But this query is throwing an error. Can you please suggest where I am going wrong ?

```
SELECT decode(COUNT(1),0,'N','Y')
INTO v_count
FROM table C
WHERE C.column1 = ip1 
  AND (CASE
          WHEN ip2 IS NOT NULL 
             THEN c.column2 = ip2 
       END);
```

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` expressions in `WHERE` and `ON` clauses.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: `AND (ip2 is NULL or c.column2 = ip2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT decode(COUNT(1),0,'N','Y')
    INTO   v_count
    FROM   table C
    WHERE  C.column1 = ip1 
    AND (ip2 IS NULL OR c.column2 = ip2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
SELECT decode(COUNT(1),0,'N','Y')
    INTO   v_count
    FROM   table C
    WHERE  C.column1 = @ip1
    AND C.column2 = isnull(@ip2, C.column2)
```

...note that this will NOT work if colmn2 can contain NULL values.

Comment: Since I am using Oracle RDBMS , the above query is not working.

Comment: Using Tags to identify the systems you are asking questions about will avoid these problems.